# jquery autocomplete not filter and showing all results

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this simple JsonResult action that I need to filter according to name and in case it does not exists add the name to the Db. how ever , my autocomplete results just get me all the list in my table after typing 2 letters ignoring my typing , 
My code:

```
   public JsonResult GetSubjectsName(string term)
    {
        var results = db.Subject.Where(s => term == null ||
        s.SubjectName.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).Select(x => new
        { id = x.SubjectId, value = x.SubjectName  }).Distinct().ToList();
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#term").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "GetSubjectsName",
                data: "{'keywords': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.value,
                            value: item.value,
                            id: item.id,
                        }
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
    });
```

Comment: Please format your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with above code is your action `GetSubjectsName` taking a parameter called `term` but while passing in the ajax you are passing the parameter as `'keywords'`So change your code to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("#term").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "GetSubjectsName",
                data: { term: request.term },
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.value,
                            value: item.value,
                            id: item.id,
                        }
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
    });

});
</script>
```